# Separate databases in symfony 4

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, symfony

I am creating an application is `symfony` (**4.1**) and I want to separate identity management in a separated database.

I have then configure doctine as follow

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    default_connection: default
    connections:
      default:
        url: '%env(DATABASE_URL)%'
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        mapping_types:
          enum: string
      identity:
        url: '%env(IDENTITY_DATABASE_URL)%'
        driver: 'pdo_pgsql'
  orm:
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
      default:
        connection: default
        mappings:
          App:
            is_bundle: false
            type: annotation
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
            prefix: 'App\Entity'

      identity:
        auto_mapping: true
        connection: identity
        mappings:
          ACL:
            is_bundle: false
            type: annotation
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Identity'
            prefix: 'App\Entity\Identity'
```

In a `contoller`, I want to retrieve `users` from **identity** database.

There is the way in use

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class, 'identity')->findAll();
```

Running `php bin/console server:run` it appears that this following code use the **default** database, instead of **identity** one.

Have I missed anything to enable sharding in `symfony` ?

Regards,

Comment: Maybe because the `dbal` connection for `orm:identity:connection` should be `acl` instead of `identity` (_that doesn't exist_).

Comment: @gp_sflover wrong copy/paste, it is indeed **identity**

Answer (score 1):

You have to inject the proper entity manager (i.e. identity). The corresponding service name is "doctrine.orm.identit_entity_manager".

If you want it in a controller I would suggest to bind this service as an argument in services.yaml:

```
App\Controller\FooController:
        bind:
            $identityManager: '@doctrine.orm.identity_entity_manager'
```

Then in your controller just inject it through autowiring and use it as expected:

```
class FooController extends AbstractController {

/**
 * @Route("/bar", name="bar")
 */
public function bar($identityManager) {
    ...
    $identityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findAll();
    ...
}
```

I have downloaded and run your project from github. Turns out that as I have already noticed in my comments, the problem was the bad configuration of the entity managers in doctrine.yaml. In order to have your program correctly work (it did for me) you have create two new directories (/src/Entity/First, /src/Entity/Second), place the files First.php and Second.php in these directories respectively, then to change your configuration in doctrine.yaml to

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    default_connection: default
    connections:
        default:
            url: '%env(DATABASE_URL)%'
            driver: 'pdo_mysql'
            server_version: '5.7'
            charset: utf8mb4
        second:
            url: '%env(SECOND_DATABASE_URL)%'
            driver: 'pdo_mysql'
            server_version: '5.7'
            charset: utf8mb4

orm:
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection: default
            mappings:
                Main:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: annotation
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/First'
                    prefix: 'App\Entity\First'
                    alias: First
        second:
            connection: second
            mappings:
                Second:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: annotation
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Second'
                    prefix: 'App\Entity\Second'
                    alias: Second
```

And you are good to go.

The problem was that you had both entity managers configured to handle the same entities (by the "dir" and "prefix" options in orm section). That led to conflicts with unpredictable behaviour. Indeed because of this conflict it was the first entity manager that was called inside the repository of the Second class.

Comment: thanks for this idea, but it has the same result for me
*********************
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'xxxxxx.users' doesn't exist" at /home/waghanza/workspace/pandacraft/v2/api/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 62

Comment: Could you check if in reality the users's table does exist through phpPgAdmin or something like that?

Comment: yeah sure, it exists
in fact, when trying to collect users collection (normally in a pg database), I have a mysql error => so I know doctrine using the default connection (a mysql one)

Comment: could you debug the entity manager you use through dump($identityManager);?

Comment: I have a failure [critical] Uncaught PHP Exception RuntimeException: "Controller "App\Controller\MenuController::index()" requires that you provide a value for the "$identityManager" argument
perhaps, it is misconfiguration on my-side

Comment: Have you used the configuration I proposed above? Please provide your configuration code.

Comment: I've (re)implemented that, and the controller code https://github.com/waghanza/multidb-sf/blob/master/src/Controller/ApplicationController.php#L17 is still failing (all my code is **public**)

Comment: You have use different directories for entities First and Second and then configure properly the mappings for the entity_managers in doctrine.yaml: dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/First'. Currently you have both entity_managers configured to the same directory.

Comment: Also use php bin/console debug:container to check if doctrine.orm.second_entity_manager is for sure the correct service_id for your entity manager.

Comment: I have updated my answer to fully solve your problem.

Comment: I have *Specified non-existing directory xxxx as Doctrine mapping source.* then

Comment: I forgot to mention you also have to create these directories: src/Entity/First, src/Entity/Second and place the files First.php, Second.php in these directories respectively, then change the configuration. I updated my answer.

Comment: thanks for you tenancity, but it seems not to work. there is an issue on my repo https://github.com/waghanza/multidb-sf and I've asked doctrine community https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/7384 but it seems that doctrine do not support to have two separated connections

Comment: I had myself your project to work properly. Furthermore I have also lots of personal projects working with two doctrine database connections. So definitely there isn't any doctrine issue here. Are you sure you have done what you had to do?